# Two image compare using win32 api c#

Tags: c#, image-comparison

i have two images and i want to compare two image and want to get difference. i search google and found a link from where i copy paste the code for image comparison using win32 api.
so this is the url
http://blog.bobcravens.com/2009/04/create-a-remote-desktop-viewer-using-c-and-wcf/

here i am pasting the code.

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        Bitmap _prevBitmap = new Bitmap(@"d:\prev.jpg");
        Bitmap _newBitmap = new Bitmap(@"d:\current.jpg");

        Rectangle bounds = GetBoundingBoxForChanges(_prevBitmap, _newBitmap);
        if (bounds == Rectangle.Empty)
        {
        }

        Bitmap diff = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(diff);
        g.DrawImage(_newBitmap, 0, 0, bounds, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        g.Dispose();

        // Set the current bitmap as the previous to prepare
        //    for the next screen capture.
        //
        diff.Save(@"d:\diff.bmp");

        //return diff;
    }

    private Rectangle GetBoundingBoxForChanges(Bitmap _prevBitmap, Bitmap _newBitmap)
    {
        // The search algorithm starts by looking
        //    for the top and left bounds. The search
        //    starts in the upper-left corner and scans
        //    left to right and then top to bottom. It uses
        //    an adaptive approach on the pixels it
        //    searches. Another pass is looks for the
        //    lower and right bounds. The search starts
        //    in the lower-right corner and scans right
        //    to left and then bottom to top. Again, an
        //    adaptive approach on the search area is used.
        //

        // Note: The GetPixel member of the Bitmap class
        //    is too slow for this purpose. This is a good
        //    case of using unsafe code to access pointers
        //    to increase the speed.
        //

        // Validate the images are the same shape and type.
        //
        if (_prevBitmap.Width != _newBitmap.Width ||
            _prevBitmap.Height != _newBitmap.Height ||
            _prevBitmap.PixelFormat != _newBitmap.PixelFormat)
        {
            // Not the same shape...can't do the search.
            //
            return Rectangle.Empty;
        }

        // Init the search parameters.
        //
        int width = _newBitmap.Width;
        int height = _newBitmap.Height;
        int left = width;
        int right = 0;
        int top = height;
        int bottom = 0;

        BitmapData bmNewData = null;
        BitmapData bmPrevData = null;
        try
        {
            // Lock the bits into memory.
            //
            bmNewData = _newBitmap.LockBits(
                new Rectangle(0, 0, _newBitmap.Width, _newBitmap.Height),
                ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, _newBitmap.PixelFormat);
            bmPrevData = _prevBitmap.LockBits(
                new Rectangle(0, 0, _prevBitmap.Width, _prevBitmap.Height),
                ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, _prevBitmap.PixelFormat);

            // The images are ARGB (4 bytes)
            //
            int numBytesPerPixel = 4;

            // Get the number of integers (4 bytes) in each row
            //    of the image.
            //
            int strideNew = bmNewData.Stride / numBytesPerPixel;
            int stridePrev = bmPrevData.Stride / numBytesPerPixel;

            // Get a pointer to the first pixel.
            //
            // Note: Another speed up implemented is that I don't
            //    need the ARGB elements. I am only trying to detect
            //    change. So this algorithm reads the 4 bytes as an
            //    integer and compares the two numbers.
            //
            System.IntPtr scanNew0 = bmNewData.Scan0;
            System.IntPtr scanPrev0 = bmPrevData.Scan0;

            // Enter the unsafe code.
            //
            unsafe
            {
                // Cast the safe pointers into unsafe pointers.
                //
                int* pNew = (int*)(void*)scanNew0;
                int* pPrev = (int*)(void*)scanPrev0;

                // First Pass - Find the left and top bounds
                //    of the minimum bounding rectangle. Adapt the
                //    number of pixels scanned from left to right so
                //    we only scan up to the current bound. We also
                //    initialize the bottom & right. This helps optimize
                //    the second pass.
                //
                // For all rows of pixels (top to bottom)
                //
                for (int y = 0; y < _newBitmap.Height; ++y)
                {
                    // For pixels up to the current bound (left to right)
                    //
                    for (int x = 0; x < left; ++x)
                    {
                        // Use pointer arithmetic to index the
                        //    next pixel in this row.
                        //
                        if ((pNew + x)[0] != (pPrev + x)[0])
                        {
                            // Found a change.
                            //
                            if (x < left)
                            {
                                left = x;
                            }
                            if (x > right)
                            {
                                right = x;
                            }
                            if (y < top)
                            {
                                top = y;
                            }
                            if (y > bottom)
                            {
                                bottom = y;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // Move the pointers to the next row.
                    //
                    pNew += strideNew;
                    pPrev += stridePrev;
                }

                // If we did not find any changed pixels
                //    then no need to do a second pass.
                //
                if (left != width)
                {
                    // Second Pass - The first pass found at
                    //    least one different pixel and has set
                    //    the left & top bounds. In addition, the
                    //    right & bottom bounds have been initialized.
                    //    Adapt the number of pixels scanned from right
                    //    to left so we only scan up to the current bound.
                    //    In addition, there is no need to scan past
                    //    the top bound.
                    //

                    // Set the pointers to the first element of the
                    //    bottom row.
                    //
                    pNew = (int*)(void*)scanNew0;
                    pPrev = (int*)(void*)scanPrev0;
                    pNew += (_newBitmap.Height - 1) * strideNew;
                    pPrev += (_prevBitmap.Height - 1) * stridePrev;

                    // For each row (bottom to top)
                    //
                    for (int y = _newBitmap.Height - 1; y > top; y--)
                    {
                        // For each column (right to left)
                        //
                        for (int x = _newBitmap.Width - 1; x > right; x--)
                        {
                            // Use pointer arithmetic to index the
                            //    next pixel in this row.
                            //
                            if ((pNew + x)[0] != (pPrev + x)[0])
                            {
                                // Found a change.
                                //
                                if (x > right)
                                {
                                    right = x;
                                }
                                if (y > bottom)
                                {
                                    bottom = y;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        // Move up one row.
                        //
                        pNew -= strideNew;
                        pPrev -= stridePrev;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            int xxx = 0;
        }
        finally
        {
            // Unlock the bits of the image.
            //
            if (bmNewData != null)
            {
                _newBitmap.UnlockBits(bmNewData);
            }
            if (bmPrevData != null)
            {
                _prevBitmap.UnlockBits(bmPrevData);
            }
        }

        // Validate we found a bounding box. If not
        //    return an empty rectangle.
        //
        int diffImgWidth = right - left + 1;
        int diffImgHeight = bottom - top + 1;
        if (diffImgHeight < 0 || diffImgWidth < 0)
        {
            // Nothing changed
            return Rectangle.Empty;
        }

        // Return the bounding box.
        //
        return new Rectangle(left, top, diffImgWidth, diffImgHeight);
    }
```

when GetBoundingBoxForChanges() call then i am getting error and error message is **Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.**

error occur at this code if ((pNew + x)[0] != (pPrev + x)[0])

so i am not being able to find out the reason. how to fix this error. please guide. thanks

Comment: Silly question, but using 'unsafe' sometimes requires compiling differently, or at least switching on some flag, have you tried that?

Comment: @Davio That would result in a compile-time error, not a runtime error.

Comment: i change something for avoiding compilation error. i am getting runtime error.

Comment: why negative mark. i post here because i am getting error and not being able to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: @Rotem okay, still it was a good starting point :)

Comment: Do the two images have the same width and height? and what is the value of `x` and `y` when it errors out? you may need to debug and step through each scan line to find the bad `y` (it will likely be 0 or close to the end), once you have that break on the bad `y` then step though each loop of `x` to find which x it is erroring out on (again likely to be either the first or near the end.)

Comment: yes i will try. can u please take two image and take my routine to just for testing purpose why it is giving error. thanks

Comment: i found this routine works perfectly when image type would be PNG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  bmNewData = _newBitmap.LockBits(...., _newBitmap.PixelFormat);
```

This algorithm implicitly assumes that a pixel has 4 bytes and can be addressed with an `int*`.  It however fails to provide that guarantee.  Asking for `_newBitmap.PixelFormat` in LockBits() is **not** sufficient, that just asks for the same format that the original image used.  You'll get a hard crash if the images are 24bpp for example, very common.

Explicitly ask for 32bppArgb instead.

Comment: your tips really works. the moment i change from this newBitmap.PixelFormat to PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb then my existing routine started works instead of giving error. can u please discuss in bit details what is there in PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb as a result the moment i use PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb then my routine works but this same routine gives error in case of _newBitmap.PixelFormat. thanks for great help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the Win32 API you could use a managed image processing library such as [AForge.NET](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/). In the [documentation](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/) look for the `AForge.Imaging.Filters.Difference` class. It works with `Bitmap` objects so you will have to make minimal changes to your program.

```
Bitmap overlayImage;
Bitmap sourceImage;

//ToDo: Load the two images.        

// Create filter.
Difference filter = new Difference(overlayImage);
// Apply the filter and return a new bitmap that is the difference between the source and overlay images.
Bitmap resultImage = filter.Apply(sourceImage);

// If you don't want a new image the you can apply the filter directly to the source image.
filter.ApplyInPlace(sourceImage);
```

Comment: i go to AForge.NET site. it is great because it is open source. but i do not understand one thing is it fast like win32 api for image comparison ?? give me some insight about the performance.

Comment: suppose i have two same identical image with same height & width. u have shown the AForge routine to get the difference in image. suppose you have two images of your desktop with small difference called img1 and img2. with the help of AForge we can get the difference that u have shown but after getting the difference how can i apply the diff image img3 on my first image img1 with the exact location as a result 3rd image will look like img2 image. is it possible with AForge library.if yes can you show me the sample code. thanks

Comment: @Thomas I'm not sure about the performance. You could compare both implementations by timing the operations. It surelly doesn't use GetPixel if this is what you are concerned. Internally it uses an UnmanagedImage object that wraps an image in unmanaged memory in the same way the implementation in your question does.

Comment: @Thomas I'm not sure I follow. You want to take the difference and add it to the first image? If so then there is an AForge.Imaging.Filters.Add class for that can be used the same way as AForge.Imaging.Filters.Difference.

Comment: thanks can u give me some code snippet for taking the difference and add it to the first image. u said it is possible by AForge.Imaging.Filters.Add. can u plzz show me with sample code. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the mechanism that I use to calculate image differences in C#. Note that it need to be compiled with the [unsafe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) directive. Hope it helps:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using log4net;

namespace ImageDiff
{
    public class ImageDifferences
    {
        private static ILog mLog = LogManager.GetLogger("ImageDifferences");

        public static unsafe Bitmap PixelDiff(Image a, Image b)
        {
            if (!a.Size.Equals(b.Size)) return null;
            if (!(a is Bitmap) || !(b is Bitmap)) return null;

            return PixelDiff(a as Bitmap, b as Bitmap);
        }

        public static unsafe Bitmap PixelDiff(Bitmap a, Bitmap b)
        {
            Bitmap output = new Bitmap(
                Math.Max(a.Width, b.Width),
                Math.Max(a.Height, b.Height),
                PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

            Rectangle recta = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, a.Size);
            Rectangle rectb = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, b.Size);
            Rectangle rectOutput = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, output.Size);

            BitmapData aData = a.LockBits(recta, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            BitmapData bData = b.LockBits(rectb, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            BitmapData outputData = output.LockBits(rectOutput, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

            try
            {
                byte* aPtr = (byte*)aData.Scan0;
                byte* bPtr = (byte*)bData.Scan0;
                byte* outputPtr = (byte*)outputData.Scan0;
                int len = aData.Stride * aData.Height;

                for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                {
                    // For alpha use the average of both images (otherwise pixels with the same alpha won't be visible)
                    if ((i + 1) % 4 == 0)
                        *outputPtr = (byte)((*aPtr + *bPtr) / 2);
                    else
                        *outputPtr = (byte)~(*aPtr ^ *bPtr);

                    outputPtr++;
                    aPtr++;
                    bPtr++;
                }

                return output;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                mLog.Error("Error calculating image differences: " + ex.Message);
                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                a.UnlockBits(aData);
                b.UnlockBits(bData);
                output.UnlockBits(outputData);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i would definitely test your code. what return output; will hold only difference. if yes then can you please tell me how can i merge the difference on first image later. please please tell me this logic how to stich the difference on first image at the exact location with difference. thanks

Comment: Merging images is a different and much more complex problem. The problem I post here is how to diff same size images. A merge algorithm is something that I don't really know.

Comment: sorry ur code did not generate right diff image. take two image with same height & width with little difference and run your code against those image and save the diff image in ur file system. then u can understand ur code did not work well. thanks

Comment: just test ur code with two image having same height & width. better take two screen shot of ur desktop with little diff and then compare two image with ur code. thanks